# Firefox profile got deleted. How to restore it?

Tags: firefox, restore, firefox-profile

While browsing just a while ago, my pages were suddenly not showing proper HTML mark-up anymore. Like if a proxy was blocking images.

I then restarted Firefox (A 64bit build called Waterfox to be exact) and I get the standard Mozilla interface, all add-ons are gone as well as my bookmarks and skins.

How can I restore this previous profile?

Comment: Operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox profiles are found in the following location.

C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles

See the following for managing profiles. 
http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Managing-profiles

Also see the following for recovering data from a old profile.
http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Recovering%20important%20data%20from%20an%20old%20profile

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't use the offical Firefox before, it probably used a different directory for profiles. You can try and copy the profile from the Waterfox configuration directory to the Firefox one. Start the Firefox Profile Manager and see if it loads the profile correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes occurs if the first instance of firefox has not completely ended. Reboot or use task manager or ps-ef to see if the first instance is still running.